# Failing to load jScrollPane dynamically with content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, jscrollpane

I want to reinitialise jScrollPane when new content is added loaded to the div, heres what I got so far:

```
var pane = $('.content_pane')

function loadContent() {
            $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
             $('.content_pane').jScrollPane();
             pane.reinitialise();
        }
```

It sort of breaks the page, but I'm new to JavaScript so I figure probably doing something wrong.

Updated :

```
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent)

    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show(1,hideLoader());
        $('.content_pane').jScrollPane();
     pane.reinitialise(); 

    }
```

It still only loads once?!

Update 2:

```
function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent)

    }

    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show(1,hideLoader());
        $('.content_pane').jScrollPane();
            var api = $('.content_pane').jScrollPane(
    {
        showArrows:true,
        maintainPosition: false
    }
).data('jsp');

        api.getContentPane();
        api.reinitialise();
    }
```

HTML :

```
 <div id="content_pane" class="content_pane">
        <div id="content" >  
        <!-- content delivered here -->     
         </div>
    </div>
```

It's quite straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
$('.content_pane').jScrollPane();
pane.reinitialise();
```

Is called before you receive data. Consider moving this code to `showNewContent`.

And remove`()` from `showNewContent()`. It is callback. You should give function, not call it. Call to `jScrollPane` should be made only once.

Here is corrected version:

```
$('.content_pane').jScrollPane();
function loadContent() {
    $('#content').load(toLoad,'', function(){
        showNewContent();
        pane.reinitialise(); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jScrollPane 2 you need to use the getContentPane method to get a reference to the pane to load the content into as in this example:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ajax.html

I'm not sure of the structure of your HTML (where `#content` is relative to `.content-pane`) so I can't give you a complete example. However another problem I notice in your code is that `pane` is a reference to the jQuery object containing your pane. If you want to get a reference to the [API](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html) (which has the reinitialise method on it) then you'll need to access the `.data('jsp')` property after initialising jScrollPane. However there is no need to call `reinitialise` directly after `jScrollPane` anyway - they both have the same effect once a pane is initialised...

Comment: I added my html structure, for reference.